# How to find your Authentication Keys in Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

A prerequisite for upgrading Magento 2.0 is:

*For upgrade or update, you must use the same authentication keys you used to install the Magento software. For example, you cannot use Magento CE authentication keys to update or upgrade Magento EE or vice versa.*

How or where can I find my Authentication Keys ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find your authentication keys from magento connect account.

You have to first login with your magento account. If you haven't magento connect account you have to create first from link [Magento Connect](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer/account/login/).

If already account then login with your username and password otherwise **register** your account from above link.

After Login with your account,

Go to **Connect Tab** (By default open with connect tab).
Click on **Developers** button from open page.

Now you have to select **secure keys** from left sidebar.

You have to generate `new secure keys` if already not available.
Otherwise you have to

> Use Public key as Username and Private key as Password

This is the authentication key for your magento.

Comment: Yes, I did that earlier. But the instructions for upgrade state "you must use the same authentication keys you used to install the Magento software". I just don't remember ever having keys when I first installed Magento 2.0.0. I simply downloaded the product and installed it. Anyway, forging ahead now and trying to upgrade again.

Comment: you can try with same key if others key then its show error otherwise your process are updated.

Comment: Thank you @Rakesh. At what point in the Upgrade process will you know that the keys are not correct? Do you get an error message? Do you get a warning? Do you get a notification message? Or does the upgrade simply halt and sit in a frozen state (as it seems to be doing at the moment for me)? [see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114275/how-long-to-wait-for-a-magento-2-x-upgrade]

Comment: you have display Bad credentials error on top.

Comment: So does that mean you cannot proceed then?

Comment: yes you have to first give right credential to upgrade your system

Comment: So if you do not give the right credentials then an error message appears on screen and you are not able to move forward through the upgrade process? Is that correct @Rakesh?

Comment: yes, if you want to upgrade process you have to give right credential first.

Comment: So if you do not give the right credentials then an error message appears on screen and you are not able to move forward through the upgrade process? Is that correct @Rakesh?

Comment: yes. this is correct

Comment: Then you should check out my other 2 posts at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114275/how-long-to-wait-for-a-magento-2-x-upgrade and http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114292/how-to-tell-if-system-upgrade-is-still-running-via-web-interface -- would be very, very, very, extremely very and highly very curious to know what I am doing wrong!!